# Unity 3D C#- Parsing Error with FixedUpdate()

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, monodevelop, parsing-error

I was working on a game in Unity and C#, and to fix the janky movement of a projectile, i decided to switch a function from `Update()` to `FixedUpdate()`, it gives me a parsing error at line 28,1, with no additional information:

`Assets/Scripts/MoveTank.cs(28,1): error CS8025: Parsing error`

`Line 28 is a random "}" in my code, and line 1 is the typical:`

```
    using UnityEngine;
```

Even when I switched back to normal `Update()`, it still gives me the error. Now here's the weird part. When I close Unity and Monodevelop, and then reopen them, the game runs well with no error. But when I mess with that line again, it gives me the same error until I reopen the program again.

I also had this happen to me earlier with a random error that didn't make sense. When I closed and reopened Unity, it worked fine.

Is this just a glitch, or is there more to it?

Comment: Post your complete `MoveTank` code

Comment: Never mind. There was just an extra "}" in my code (at line 28, that was a mistake) that it just looked over for some reason when it re-opened. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

The only issue was that there was an extra "}" at line 28. For some reason, it looked over this when Unity re-opened.